# Checkbox value equals php variable

Tags: php, checkbox

this may be a redundant question, but i gave up searching for answers already.
My question is, how do I pass in a php variable into the checkbox value. 
For an example if I have `$theRowID = $row['id']`, I want to make the check box value as,
checkbox value ="`$theRowID`"

Comment: You mean selected check box?

Comment: curious to know why would you have an ID from a db table (generally a unique integer) as a checkbox value?

Comment: @flauntster probably checking a list of different IDs. Like selecting which products you want to buy. Any product with a check beside it would be added to your cart.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan: yes a selected checkbox.

Comment: @mike: hi mike the id from DB is basically auto increasing id

Comment: @mike: i am working on a booking system. i have a form that saves all the input into the database. my view.php echo all the information from the database in table format. what i want to do is to place checkbox next to each row and then upon selecting the checkbox i want the checkbox to correspond to the row id from the db. i also want click on "approve" button to make sure the ticked rows are inserted in another table from the same DB.

Comment: i have research alot for solutions but maybe i do not know how implement it in my codes

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating your HTML in a .php file, you can do it like this:

```
// assuming you're looping through a query result, also assuming mysqli
$query = mysqli_query('SELECT id FROM tbl');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="'. $row['id'] .'" />';
}
```

Comment: hi i just tried it and i got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', i always get this error when i am trying the respective codes.

Comment: Are you in a `<?php` block? Sounds like you have a typo in your actual code. The syntax in my answer is correct.